# Resize Frame when Ajax is finished

Tags: jquery, iframe, jquery-events

I am trying to resize an iframe after the content is loaded. The page (that is loaded into the iframe) has some controls that cause it to load addition information to the bottom of the page, and it does this through JQuery's `$.ajax()` method.

I have tried using `$(document).ajaxComplete()` but that ends up getting registered before the `$.ajax()` methods `success` event. What I want to do is register an event for after the success event.

For example:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    resizeIframe();
    $(document).ajaxComplete("resizeIframe");
    $(document).load("resizeIframe");
    
});

function resizeIframe()
{
    $(window).parent().height($("body").height());
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
}
</script>
```

This works properly on statically loaded pages. However, if I have something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $("someObject").on('click', function (){
       $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'someurl.php',
            success: function(data) 
            {
                 $("body").append(data);
            }
       });
    });
</script>
```

then the `resizeIframe` gets called before the `.ajax` success function (meaning that the DOM doesn't contain those addition elements, and thus the page is the wrong height. I would like to avoid adding `resizeIframe` to every ajax call I make, is there an event I can use to resolve this?

**Update**

I have tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    resizeIframe();
    $(document).load(function(){ resizeIframe();});
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
            setTimeout(resizeIframe, 0);
    });
});
```

and it seems to be working in Firefox 21. However, it is not working in IE10 (and I have to be backwards compatible to IE8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local events will always be executed before the global event (Local Success -> Global Success -> Local complete -> Global Complete). You can set a global `success` event:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess("resizeIframe");
```

API Ref: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/

And then specify a local `complete` event:

```
url: 'someurl.php',
complete: function(data) 
{
    $("body").append(data);
}
```

Note that the complete function runs whenever an AJAX call finishes.

Comment: Doesn't the success function that is defined first run first, meaning that the resizeIframe method would run before the $.ajax Success element?

Comment: I just tested, and the $(document).ajaxSuccess() method fires before the success element in the $.ajax method

Comment: Ahh yep, just tried it. Another idea, create your own global handler, and bind it in the local success event?

Comment: That sounds promising, do you have an example of something like that?

Comment: Actually, rather than calling the `success` handler, you can call the `complete` handler, check for errors. The global success executes before the local complete.

Comment: I tried that, and it seems to work correctly in FF 21, but not it IE10

Comment: Verify that IE is actually sending the data, seems buggy on 64 bit desktop, check the console.

Comment: I just checked my IE console. I was on IE8 standards, when I switched to IE10 standards, it worked fine. Do you have any idea what compatibility issue would stop this from working on IE 8?

Comment: No idea on that one, going to have to look into it.